# Why is inner class TreeMap.Entry<K,V> generic?

Tags: java, generics, collections, treemap

Why is this so?

```
static final class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V>
```

Why not just do like:

```
 static final class Entry implements Map.Entry<K,V>
```

Comment: To provide type-safety? If it wasn't you'd have to cast, and lose compile-time type safety?

Comment: Well, why don't you make your own `Entry` subclass using the latter way, and see how it goes... Because that's what a good answer needs to do anyway.

Comment: But Entry class already knows about type K and V from the top class TreeMap. And It still will be type safely. It looks like Entry knows about TreeMap K and V, but create its own parameters type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But Entry class already knows about type K and V from the top class TreeMap. And It still will be type safely. It looks like Entry knows about TreeMap K and V, but create its own parameters type

As a matter of fact it doesn't:

```
public class Main<T> {
    static final class Entry {
        T t;           // ERROR: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type T            
        void f(T t) {} // ERROR: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type T
    }
}
```

On the other hand, the following compiles without errors:

```
public class Main<T> {
    static final class Entry<T> {
        T t;
        void f(T t) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it's static, naturally. It has no specific instance of `Main` to refer to.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the key to understand why Entry can't use the outer map parameters lies in the `static` keyword, used to declare it.

The actual type of K,V is known only to *instances* of the outer Map, while Entry knows only of the Map *class*. So Entry must be a generic type, with its own generic parameters. Never mind they are named K,V as in the outer Class (Map), they identify different parameters.

Comment: I really like your explanation. However, isn't it the case that `K` and `V` don't exist at all during runtime, due to type erasure?

Answer (score 0):

```
static final class Entry implements Map.Entry<K,V>
```

This is not a valid statement in Java as Entry interface is parametrized and there is no support for auto inference of parametrized type from surrounding elements. Java 7 has taken a right step in this direction with introduction of diamond operator. However, we need to wait until JLS defines it to infer type from interface itself.